# Unity prevent force apply on re-enable Physics2D.IgnoreCollision

Tags: unity, physics

I'm making 2d platformer game. My player and enemies  are rb with body type `Dynamic`. I choose dynamic for enemies because enemy need physics ( jumping, colliding with ground, etc)
I'm using  `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision`  for disabling and again enabling collision between Player and Enemies. When player lost life shield is applied on player.Here is code :

Disabling collision

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
       {

    Player player = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(collision.collider, gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), true);
        StartCoroutine(EnableCollision(player.timeShildActiveFixed, collision.collider, gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>()));

        if (player.playerState != Player.PlayerState.SHIELD)
        {
            playerLostLife();
            player.ActiveShield();
        }
    }

}
```

Enabling collision again:

```
    private IEnumerator EnableCollision(float delay, Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(collider1, collider2, false);
}
```

This work well but I my problem is that some force is applied on enemy before ignoring collision and enemy is changing its position ( on enemy because mass is set to 0.01 , but on Player mass is 1). This force is more visible when player not moving and shield is disabling and collison between player and enemy occur again and player get shiled again.

I can't work with different layer with disabled physics for Player and Enemy because I need collision between them.

Can someone help me with this? How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: "I can't work with different layer with disabled physics for Player and Enemy because I need collision between them." That's a very narrow way of thinking about the problem. Why not give the player two colliders? One on a layer that interacts with enemies and one on a layer that interacts with the terrain. Disable the enemy-interacting collider in the player's prefab so that when you spawn the player, it has no collision with enemies until you decide to turn it on. You can even make this enemy-interacting collider a trigger so it applies no forces, and detect it with OnTriggerEnter 2D instead.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion can you please help me how can I do this ?I don't know how to add collider to specific layer?  I'm new to Unity

Comment: The layer drop-down is at the top-right of the Inspector. This is [explained in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html), as is [using layers to filter collisions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html). You can use multiple layers for your player by putting its colliders on child objects that have a different layer set than their parent/siblings.

Comment: thanks @DMGregory, You mad my day. Please write this as answer I will accept it. Sorry for your time bro

Comment: If you've solved your problem, I recommend writing up your solution as an answer. Since you have a working, tested project with this fix, you're in a better position to explain what you changed, or even include screenshots showing the steps.